# sourcing bash script does not acquire function def

Tags: bash, shell-script, bash-functions

This is a weird one - it should work.

I have this file  `/home/foo/waldo.sh`

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

waldo(){

   if [[ -z $(command -v waldo) ]]; then
       npm install -g '@oresoftware/waldo' || {
         return 1;
      }
   fi

   command waldo "$@"
}


export -f waldo;
```

if I source the file with:

```
. "/home/foo/waldo.sh";
```

and then run

```
waldo
```

I get:

```
No command 'waldo' found, did you mean:
 Command 'aldo' from package 'aldo' (universe)
waldo: command not found
```

when I run `$(which waldo)`, it's empty, nothing there.

however, when I run `type waldo`, I get:

```
waldo is a function
waldo () 
{ 
    if [[ -z $(command -v waldo) ]]; then
        npm install -g '@oresoftware/waldo' || { 
            return 1
        };
    fi;
    command waldo "$@"
}
```

anyone know why it's not being sourced or whatever?

Comment: You're using command substitution too much. There's no need for `$(command ...)` or `$(which ...)`. Use the exit status of the command you're calling instead of checking for output. E.G.: `if ! command -v waldo >/dev/null; then ...`

Comment: I prefer `type -a` to `which`

Comment: @glennjackman ah yes I forgot about `type -a`, why is it better than which tho?

Comment: In this case, I need a command that looks up to see what's in the PATH only, ignoring shell functions, that should be somewhat obvious from the question right.

Comment: I think `type -f` is what I am looking for, since that suppresses bash function results

Comment: @glennjackman feel free to check out this related question https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/451542/installing-command-line-tool-if-its-not-in-the-path

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The function is found and executed but it contains

```
command waldo
```

That's what the error message refers to.

You could handle this problem in the function:

```
if hash waldo >/dev/null 2>&1; then
    command waldo "$@"
else
    echo 'ERROR: ...'
fi
```

Comment: ok thanks! then why did the if condition evaluate to false then? in other words, why didn't `command -v waldo` evaluate to empty string?

Comment: I see the update that should help, but I think in the if check to see if it's installed already, I need to use something other than `command -v waldo` ?

Comment: maybe `which waldo` instead?

Comment: @AlexanderMills Is the `npm install` executed (`set -x`)? Does it put a binary `waldo` in the `PATH`?

Comment: yeah it does put "waldo" in the $PATH